# How can I use a CSS script as a background for a Wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I found some code in CodePen.io that produces a "matrix" effect and I want to try to integrate it on my website. This is the code: https://codepen.io/gnsp/pen/vYBQZJm .

What I am trying to do is to use this script as the background for my one-page website: I want this to be shown behind text and image blocks instead of a picture or a color background.

The page builder I am using is GoodLayers and it allows a "code" block which places a block that you can write javascript in which then gets interpreted.

This is the code:

```html
<style> body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
} </style>
<div>
<canvas id= "canv" height:window.innerHeight width:window.innerWidth style="z-index=0"> </canvas>
</div>
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const w = canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
const h = canvas.height = document.body.offsetHeight;
const cols = Math.floor(w / 20) + 1;
const ypos = Array(cols).fill(0);

ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

function matrix () {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#0001';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#0f0';
  ctx.font = '15pt monospace';
  
  ypos.forEach((y, ind) => {
    const text = String.fromCharCode(70,105,68,105) ;
    const x = ind * 20;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    if (y > 100 + Math.random() * 10000) ypos[ind] = 0;
    else ypos[ind] = y + 20;
  });
}

setInterval(matrix, 50);
</script>
```

I have placed it inside a section wrapper.

[This is how it looks in the backend.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWGoF.png)

[And this is how it looks in the frontend: not centered and appears as a block that does not overlap with anything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPit8.jpg)

[That's how it looks when I scroll down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn9re.jpg)

I want for it to either move with the viewport or better- to be fixed and just cover the whole page from top to bottom.

I am extremely new to this and hardly ever hardcoded anything in CSS or JS without the use of UI of various page builders so please understand that.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/e5ukcjsx/

Comment: That still seems to be making an off-center effect which would fill viewport if it would be centered. Nonetheless, it doesn't fill the whole page and gets offscreen as you scroll down.  https://imgur.com/a/EtXkoxK

Comment: Try `canvas.style.position = "fixed";` instead. I'm also not sure that GoodLayers is a suitable way to include that code.

Comment: I pinned it to the top left corner with top:0 and left:0 and used fixed position- now it seems to be doing what I wanted! Thanks a lot!